# Tolerance Stack Up Distribution

Tags: analysis, tolerance, statistics

Suppose I've got a 2V source with 2% accuracy that I want to divide down to 1V using 5% resistors. One can easily see with Monte Carlo analysis that the worst case output voltage deviation is 7%
[image: Monte Carlo analysis of described circuit]

I'd now like to take this information and form it into a conjecture on what I'm confident the typical value of the output will be.

I've seen other posts that ended on the remark that components off the same reel don't tend to have a gaussian distribution, lower deviation parts get binned as better parts, etc. I would argue that in most cases, the network under analysis tends to be composed of several values from several manufacturers, typically from batches that pass or fail rather than being binned on account of being the least expensive passive possible. As such, I would suppose the typical distribution of errors for a diverse network of inexpensive components to be roughly Gaussian.

So then,

**Starting with the assumptions that the distribution of component tolerances is gaussian, and has a reasonable spread (say we assume 5σ manufacturing processes), how does one go about forming a confidence interval to describe the whole circuit?**

I know that the tolerance distribution of the system is the convolution of the distributions of components, and that the convolution of two gaussian distributions itself is still gaussian - but does it logically (mathematically) follow that the extremes of the output are the same number of σ apart? (e.g. assuming all components tolerances are 5σ can I in turn assume that the span of potential outputs also span 5σ?)

If one can in fact conclude the assumptions of the paragraph above, confidence intervals are relatively trivial. For this example, if 7% = 5σ then I can say with 95.45% confidence that the typical (2σ) output value is within (2/5) * 7 = 2.8% tolerance.

This fixed proportion of

*typical(95%) = *2 / (assumed σ) * worst-case**

would be an incredibly handy rule of thumb to keep in my bag of tricks. I'd love for someone proficient in both electrical engineering and statistics to either confirm the maths behind this approach, or enlighten me as to how the distributions actually interact as they're convoluted - and subsequently how to derive a confidence interval describing the output of the network.

Comment: If there are enough components, I think the central limit theorem means that the overall effect will be gaussian distributed. The classical central limit theorem requires that all parts have the same distribution, but Lindeberg's formulation of it proves that any well-behaved mixture of distributions will approach the gaussian. (I don't know enough about statistics to know what exactly "well-behaved" means here; I think it mostly means "finite".)

Answer (score 2):

> **Starting with the assumptions that the distribution of component tolerances is gaussian, and has a reasonable spread (say we assume 5σ manufacturing processes), how does one go about forming a confidence interval to describe the whole circuit?**

The key word here is confidence. You have zero confidence in your initial assumptions of Gaussian, and reasonable.

In a natural process, you could reasonably expect the law of large numbers to make the results Gaussian.

Resistor manufacturing **and their subsequent commercial supply** is most definitely not a natural process. It's not even ergodic (non time-varying).

The resistors are manufactured, to a target resistance, and you might hope that this process is reasonably Gaussian in its spread of values. Then they are selected. Your 5% tape will have had any resistors exceeding 5% removed, and more likely than not, anything meeting 1% or 2% removed and sold at a higher price. That's this month. Next month they might have had a large order for 1% types of a different value cancelled, and the entire tape has a 1% spread around a value 4% away from nominal. Halfway through the tape, the bin runs out, and they start using another bin with another value, which still meets the 5% tolerance you bought.

They only thing you can expect when you buy 5% resistors is that they will all be within 5% of the stated value.

Comment: I entirely see where you're coming from with regards to consecutive parts off of one reel - non-gaussian on account of a given manufacturer's process not being a natural process. 

However, in a circuit that uses a 10k from mfr. A, a 15k from mfr. B, a 22k from mfr. C, a 100nF from mfr. D, etc. is there a case to be made for a natural process? 

The manufacturers don't communicate amongst themselves, and often the converse of your example is the case: e.g. the demand for 0.1% parts gets dwarfed by demand for 1% - and the tighter tolerances are sold at a lower price to meet demand.

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** assume that the distribution of the components is gaussian. The only thing you can assume is that the specified tolerance is met.

So yes, 2% plus 5% is indeed 7%.

Comment: "The only thing you can assume is that the specified tolerance is met."   I've seen 82k 1% resistors that all measured around 83k.

Comment: @OskarSkog They were all skewed to the same end of the range but were within range? Or they exceeded the range, consistently, past the same end of the range? (Mostly just curious. Not arguing about anything.)

Comment: @periblepsis:  They appeared to be nicely centered around 83k, +/- 500 ohm.  I think the manufacturer did an oopsie.

Comment: @OskarSkog These were 5% E24? Because there aren't any 1% (E96) 82k resistor standard values, are there?

Comment: @periblepsis:  Not sure, it says 82k 1% on the distributor's site https://www.starelec.fi/product_info.php?products_id=9385 and IIRC the color code was gray-red-black-orange-brown.

Comment: @OskarSkog 82k 1% would be gray red black ***red*** brown. But it's not a [standard value](https://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148841/discussion-between-oskar-skog-and-periblepsis).